# Why are my Turtles delaying so much even when I increase their speed?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

When the turtle `v` is drawing the circle, the other turtles move way slower than expected.

I've tried increasing the speed of the turtles, as I thought it might go quicker, but it still stops for 3-4 seconds before moving to a different location:

```
import turtle
import random

def q():
    x=random.randint(-300,300)
    y = random.randint(-300, 300)
    z = random.randint(-300, 300)
    a = random.randint(-300, 300)



    t.goto (x,y)
    c.goto(a,z)
    t.speed(10000000000000000000000000000000000)
    c.speed(10000000000000000000000000000000000)
    v.color("purple")
    c.color("red")
    v.pensize(width=100)
    v.penup()
    v.setposition(0,-300)
    v.pendown()
    v.circle(350)
t = turtle.Turtle()
c = t.clone()
v = t.clone()
while True:
    q()
```

Comment: `c.speed(10000000000000000000000000000000000)` is no different than `c.speed("fastest")`. If you want to go faster than fastest, disable animation with `turtle.tracer(0)` and call `turtle.update()` when you want a refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that turtle `v`, which draws the large purple circle, is running at `'normal'` speed, not `'fastest'` like the other two turtles.  Fixing that, and rewriting this as a proper turtle program, speeds it up significantly without the need for `tracer()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

def q():
    x = randint(-300, 300)
    y = randint(-300, 300)
    z = randint(-300, 300)
    a = randint(-300, 300)

    t.goto(x, y)
    c.goto(a, z)

    v.circle(350)

    screen.ontimer(q)  # call again ASAP

screen = Screen()

t = Turtle()
t.speed('fastest')

c = t.clone()
c.color("red")

v = t.clone()
v.color("purple")
v.pensize(width=100)
v.penup()
v.sety(-350)
v.pendown()

q()

screen.mainloop()
```